# PHP readfile outputs wrong name

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a download.php page where the user can download an XML file. Based on a dropdown select the file get's a different name. I'm using AJAX to send the name to download.php, therefore `$_POST` returns an array with the specified data from the js. Yet when I use `readfile` to download the file, in the save file dialog the string that comes from `$_POST` is ignored.. Here is my code:

JS:

```
let formData = {
    shop: shop.val()
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: './inc/download.php',
    data: formData,
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

PHP:

```
$shop_name = $_POST['shop'];

$dir = dirname(__DIR__, 1) . "/xml/"; // Full Path
$file = "$shop_name-orders.xml";

print_r('dir:' . $dir); // dir:/my-site/xml/
print_r('file:' . $file); // file:shopname-orders.xml
print_r("dirfile: $dir$file"); // dirfile: /my-site/xml/shopname-orders.xml

// Set the content type and file headers
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $file .'"');

// Read and output the file content

if (file_exists("$dir$file")) {
    readfile("$dir$file");
} else {
    echo "Error: $file not found";
}

exit;
```

[image: screenshot from console]

And in the save file dialog that opens the name of the file is just '-orders'. $_POST is not empty it does contain the string I'm looking for, tried with isset($_POST['shop']).. I need the name of the file to be 'shopname-orders'.. Why is $_POST being ignored?

Comment: You have a security flaw in your php, you need to sanitize input. Try "../../../../../../etc/shadow". This is called a directory traversal attack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack.

Comment: can you add your outputs to the question ?

Comment: `$_POST is not empty`...how have you verified that exactly? All the evidence points the opposite way.

Comment: if I do print_r($_POST) it prints the correct string that is taken from the select option value. Also added the other print_r() outputs.

Comment: Also added a screenshot from dev tools

Comment: @Reda Bourial, thanks for pointing this out. For now this is all on localhost so for now I'm not worried about that..

Comment: "_the file is just '-orders'_" Without the extension `.xml`?

Comment: @brombeer, yes in the save file dialog it doesn't include shop_name and the file extension at the end, but it does saves it as an xml file.

Comment: I don't see how you could even _get_ a "save file" dialog here in this instance. You are making a _background_ request - so the response will not trigger a download dialog automatically, _you_ would need to write additional JavaScript code to achieve that - which according to what you have shown us, you didn't.

Comment: @CBroe, Sorry I haven't included my HTML, I didn't thought it would be relevant since it's just 2 buttons and a dropdown.. Basically, one of the buttons is "Generate", that generates an XML file. After the file is generated the button changes to an anchor that links to download.php which actually triggers the save file dialog.

Comment: _"an anchor that links to download.php"_ - clicking that will cause a GET request then, so of course there are no POST parameters available in the script.